# Creating new array of objects from specific values in 2 different arrays (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I got these 2 arrays:

```
const data = [
  { url: 'google.com', title: 'google', social: false, corporate: true },
  { url: 'facebook.com', title: 'facebook', social: true, corporate: true }
 ];

const valuesToExtract = ['url', 'title'];
```

I need to get to this result:

```
const result = [
 { url: 'somepath[0].url', title: 'somepath[0].title' },
 { url: 'somepath[1].url', title: 'somepath[1].title' }
]
```

I tried this way:

```
const newArray = [];    
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (const value of valuesToExtract ) {
    const newObject = {};
      newObject[value] = `somepath[${i}].${value}`;
      newArray.push(newObject);
  }
}
```

But the result I get is:

```
const result = [
  { url: 'somepath[0].url' },
  { title: 'somepath[0].title' },
  { url: 'somepath[1].url' },
  { title: 'somepath[1].title' }
]
```

How can I do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to change a bit of where to put stuff in your nested loops. You need two loops:

1. The first loop goes over the `data` array
2. For every data point, the 2nd loop goes over the `valuesToExtract`

Therefore, you only want to `push` your `newObject` once the 2nd loop has finished (meaning once `valuesToExtract` has finished extracting). This way, you get a `newObject` for every `data` item.

```js
const data = [
  { url: 'google.com', title: 'google', social: false, corporate: true },
  { url: 'facebook.com', title: 'facebook', social: true, corporate: true }
 ];

const valuesToExtract = ['url', 'title'];
const newArray = [];    
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // Create a new Object for every data item
  const newObject = {};
  for (const value of valuesToExtract ) {
      newObject[value] = `somepath[${i}].${value}`;
  }
  newArray.push(newObject);
}

console.log(newArray)
```